# Can I update a Joomla module without uninstalling?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I am maintaining a Joomla module that gets installed on a site to which I have no file transfer privileges. Of course I do development in a test instance of Joomla where I do have file transfer privileges, and there I can edit module code and reload pages and everything works well.

However, when it comes time to move the updated module to the "live" site, the only option seems to be to uninstall the existing version of the module and then upload the new version of the module. If I just try to re-upload the module using the Joomla "Extension Manager" install option, I get an "Another module is already using directory" error.

Uninstalling, however, also wipes out all the "positions" that have been set up to use this module with some extensive parameter tweaking.

Is there a way to get Joomla to let me overwrite the old version of the module with the new version? Is there something I can put in the module's XML description to facilitate this?

The sites I am writing for are running Joomla 1.5.23.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's possible by changing the install line in your xml to the following before zipping it up:

```
<install version="1.5" type="module" client="site" method="upgrade">
```

Just tested it on a 1.5.23 and it kept my previous module settings but also copied over any changed code.

Comment: Great! That does the trick @Trev, thanks. I had to make a slight change since my XML did not have an "install" element, but it looks like doing this in the "moinstall" works just as well.

`<mosinstall type="module" version="1.5" method="upgrade">`